# PHP code not working (registration system)

Tags: php

```
<?php

include("config.php");

$username = $_POST["usernameinput"];
$password1 = $_POST["password1input"];
$password2 = $_POST["password2input"];

/*check that the passwords match*/  error starts here

if ($password1 != $password2) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['CHECK'] = "The passwords didnt match!";
    header("location: reg.php");
}

/*checks if the passwords are empty*/

if (empty($password1)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['CHECK'] = "Your password can't be empty!";
    header("location: reg.php");
}

if (empty($password2)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['CHECK'] = "Your password can't be empty!";
    header("location: reg.php");
}

echo "Passed Password Check";  ends here

/*checks the name against the database*/

$sql = "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1 ) {

    /*Checks for the entered username in the database*/

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['CHECK'] = "A account exists under that username!";
    header("location: reg.php");

} else {

echo "Passed account check";

echo "Creating account";

/*adds account into database */

$sql="INSERT INTO `users`(`password`, `username`, `Access`) VALUES ('$password1','$username','Normal')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

/*creates table for the user*/

$sql2="CREATE TABLE $username(
   name   VARCHAR(20)              NOT NULL,
   contents VARCHAR (4000)     NOT NULL,     
   PRIMARY KEY (name)
);" ;
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);

echo "account made";

/*sets cookie then goes back to reg.php*/

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['CHECK'] = "Account has been created";
    /*header("location: reg.php");*/
}



?>
```

This page is a registration system with multiple checks i am having a problem with the password checks were they are not happening at all (the passwords can be different and it will still create a account) i think it has something to do with the database check as without it it works perfectly. also if you have any other improvements id be happy to try them.

Comment: a) you're vulnerable to **SQL Injection** - imagine a username `'; DROP TABLE users; --` use parameterized statements b) **never ever ever ever** store plain text passwords! use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include a die() statement to prevent the rest of the script from executing if any checks fail.

eg.

```
if (empty($password1)) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['CHECK'] = "Your password can't be empty!";
header("location: reg.php");
die();
}
```